# fgets() Alternative

Tags: c, strings, io

```
size_t readline_tostring(char * restrict dest, size_t size, FILE * restrict stream)
```

`fgets()` is OK yet it has some short-comings that the following `readline_tostring()` addresses for reading a *line*:

1. When the buffer is insufficient, the rest of the line is consumed (and lost).  An error is indicated.
2. In C, a *line* of input is up to and including the `'\n`'  C11 7.21.2 2.  When the streams ends with something other than a new-line, how that is handled is implementation defined behavior. J.3.12.  This code treats a `'\n`' and end-of-file as the same.  In both cases, a  `'\n'` is not include in the saved buffer.
3. If code reads a `'\0'`, that is not practical to discern with `fgets()`.  This code returns the *size* of the space used in `dest`, which includes an appended null character.
4. Lesser issues include `fgets()` handling of `NULL` augments, [small buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2410359), undefined buffer state on `ferror()` and use of `int` vs `size_t`.  The below code also clearly - I hope - handles that.
5. An alternative allocate memory: Allocating memory per external input can lead to abuse.  This allows external forces to overwhelm memory allocation.  The following does not use memory allocation like [getline substitute that will enforce 'n' as limit of characters read](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91019/getline-substitute-that-will-enforce-n-as-limit-of-characters-read)  or [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). 
   Another alternative could use *limited* allocation, but that is not done here.

**Primary review requests (of the non-test code)**

Portability concerns:  Might a common or rare case fail on some select systems?

Handling of exceptional/error cases:  Any suggested alternates?

Performance concerns are appreciated when they are backed with real measurements.

General comments (on any code).

---

The code below is listed as one file for code review convenience, yet would usually would be is separate .h, .c files.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Header info, usually in some *.h file

/*
 * Read a _line_ of text. Save characters up to a limit, and form a _string_.
 * The string saved in `dest` never contains a '\n'.
 * A null character is always appended ***1.
 * Reading only attempted in non-pathological cases.  
 * Otherwise the end-of-file flag and error flags are cleared before reading.
 *
 * Normal: The return value is greater than  0 and represents the _size_ of `dest` used.
 *     This includes all non-'\n' characters read and an appended null character. ***2
 *     Reading text "abc\n" forms string "abc" and return 4
 *
 * Exceptional cases:
 *   In these cases, the return value is 0 and `dest[0] = '\0'` except as noted.
 *   1: Pathological: Buffer invalid for string.
 *     `dest == NULL` or `size == 0` (No data is written into `dest`)
 *   2: Pathological: Stream invalid.
 *     `stream == NULL`
 *   3: End-of-file occurs and no data read.
 *     Typical end-of-file: `feof(stream)` will return true.
 *   4: Input error.
 *     `ferror(stream)` will return true.
 *     strlen(dest) is number of characters successfully read. ***3
 *   5: Buffer is too small.
 *     First `size-1` non-'\n' characters are saved in `dest[]`.
 *     Additional characters are read up to and including '\n'.  These are not saved.
 *     The end-of-file flag and error flags are cleared again.
 *     strlen(dest) is number of characters successfully save. ***3
 *
 * ***1 Except when `dest == NULL` or `size == 0`
 * ***2 If code reads a null character, it is treated like any non-'\n' character.
 * ***3 strlen(dest) does not reflect the number of characters in `dest` 
 *       if a null character was read and saved.
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
size_t readline_tostring(char * restrict dest, size_t size,
    FILE * restrict stream);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code, usually in some *.c file

size_t readline_tostring(char * restrict dest, size_t size,
    FILE * restrict stream) {
  // Handle pathological cases
  if (dest == NULL || size == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (stream == NULL) {
    dest[0] = '\0';
    return 0;
  }
  clearerr(stream);

  size_t i = 0;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    if (i < size) {
      dest[i++] = (char) ch;
    }
  }

  // Add null character termination - always
  // If too many were read
  if (i >= size) {
    dest[size - 1] = '\0';
    clearerr(stream);
    return 0;
  }
  dest[i] = '\0';

  if ((ch == EOF) && (i == 0 || ferror(stream))) { // end-of-file or error
    return 0;
  }

  clearerr(stream);
  return i + 1;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Test code

#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Sample usage showing how to discern the results.
void sample(char * restrict dest, size_t size, FILE * restrict stream) {
  size_t sz;
  while ((sz = readline_tostring(dest, size, stream)) > 0) {
    printf("Size:%zu string:\"%s\"\n", sz, dest);
  }

  // Well formed code need not perform this 1st test
  if (dest == NULL || size == 0 || stream == NULL) {
    puts("Pathological case");
  } else if (feof(stream)) {
    puts("End of file");
  } else if (ferror(stream)) {
    puts("Input error");
  } else {
    printf("Line too long: begins with <%s>\n", dest);
  }
  puts("");
}

void test4(const char *s) {
  FILE *stream = fopen("tmp.bin", "wb");
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  fwrite(s, 1, len, stream);
  fclose(stream);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf(isprint((unsigned char)s[i]) ? "%c" : "<%d>", s[i]);
  }
  puts("");

  stream = fopen("tmp.bin", "r");
  char buf[4];
  sample(buf, sizeof buf, stream);
  fclose(stream);
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main(void) {
  test4("12\nAB\n");
  test4("123\nABC\n");
  test4("1234\nABCD\n");
  test4("");
  test4("1");
  test4("12");
  test4("123");
  test4("1234");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
12<10>AB<10>
Size:3 string:"12"
Size:3 string:"AB"
End of file

123<10>ABC<10>
Size:4 string:"123"
Size:4 string:"ABC"
End of file

1234<10>ABCD<10>
Line too long: begins with <123>


End of file

1
Size:2 string:"1"
End of file

12
Size:3 string:"12"
End of file

123
Size:4 string:"123"
End of file

1234
Line too long: begins with <123>
```

Comment: When the line contains `\0` and the function returns 0 due to line-too-long or EOF or error, you cannot tell whether any of the characters beyond the first `\0` are valid.  That's in accordance with your specification, I guess, but it's hard to see how that could be desirable.

Comment: @NateEldredge When the function returns 0, and `feof()`, `ferror()` are false, the result in [those cases](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179201/fgets-alternative?noredirect=1#comment340218_179201) is a " line-too-long" and `size-1` read characters are in the buffer - some of which may be `'\0'`.  When 0 is returned and `feof()` is true, there are no characters read  and the the initial `'\0'` is the end.  Your comment best applies to the rare case 0 is returned and `ferror()` is true.  The valid characters read extend to before the first null character _and maybe more_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First impressions

The code is clear and easy to follow.  You had two choices to ignore overlength  lines (the other being a second loop to absorb the overflow).  This choice seems reasonable.

I'd consider making the parameters `const` when defining the function, just to help avoid accidents and to be extra clear:

```
size_t readline_tostring(char *const restrict dest, size_t const size,
                         FILE *const restrict stream)
{
```

### Clearing stream errors

I'm not convinced that it's right to call `clearerr()` in this code, as that can potentially hide useful information from the caller.  There's no comment to justify this, and I think there should be.

### Returning partial line

It might be better to discourage use of the partial line returned when `EOF` is reached, by setting `dest[0] = '\0'` in that case.  Arguably, client code might want to spot that there's potentially-usable results if return value is 0 but `dest[0]` is non-null (e.g. if the discarded part is within a line-terminated comment).

It's certainly better to make `dest` an empty string when we get an error.

## Tests

The test code looks a little rushed.  How do we know it's safe to overwrite `tmp.bin` in the current working directory?  We should be using `tmpfile()` or `tmpnam()` instead, and actually testing that we successfully write our temporary data.  And unlink the file afterwards (if not using `tmpfile()`, which creates an unlinked file already).

Writing the file in binary mode and reading in text mode seems like a poor choice, and I'm not convinced it's even legal on record-oriented file systems.

None of the tests are self-checking, and none include embedded NUL character or consecutive newlines.

Here's some self-checking tests.  I'm not completely happy with this, but hope it could be a start:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Sample usage showing how to discern the results.
size_t sample(char *const restrict dest, size_t const size,
              FILE *const restrict stream)
{
    size_t sz = readline_tostring(dest, size, stream);
    printf("Size:%zu string:\"%s\"\n", sz, dest);

    // Well formed code need not perform this 1st test
    if (dest == NULL || size == 0 || stream == NULL) {
        puts("Pathological case");
    } else if (feof(stream)) {
        puts("End of file");
    } else if (ferror(stream)) {
        puts("Input error");
    } else {
        printf("Line too long: begins with <%s>\n", dest);
    }

    return sz;
}

/* return a count of errors (0 for success) */
/* Varargs are (size, string) pairs of expected result */
/* Terminate with -1 */
int test4(const char *s, size_t len, ...)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf(isprint((unsigned char)s[i]) ? "%c" : "<%d>", s[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    FILE *const stream = tmpfile();
    if (!stream || fwrite(s, 1, len, stream) != len) {
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }
    rewind(stream);


    va_list args;
    va_start(args, len);

    int errors = 0;
    int expected;
    while ((expected = va_arg(args, int)) >= 0) {
        const char *s = va_arg(args, const char*);
        char buf[4];
        size_t actual = sample(buf, sizeof buf, stream);
        if (actual != (size_t)expected) {
            printf("FAIL (%d): Expected %d, got %zd\n",
                   ++errors, expected, actual);
        } else if (memcmp(buf, s, actual) != 0) {
            printf("FAIL (%d): Expected %s, got %s\n",
                   ++errors, s, buf);
        }
    }
    va_end(args);

    if (errors) {
        puts("FAILED");
    }
    puts("");

    fclose(stream);
    fflush(stdout);

    return errors;
}

int main(void) {
    /* two lines each of 4 chars and a newline */
    static const char *test_string = "1234\n"  "A\0BC\n";

    return
        + test4(test_string, 5, 0, "123", -1)
        + test4(test_string+1, 5, 4, "234", -1)
        + test4(test_string+3, 5, 2, "4", 4, "A\0B", -1)
        + test4(test_string+4, 5, 1, "",  0, "A\0BC", -1);
}
```

There are no tests for handling invalid arguments (null or zero-length buffer, null stream), nor for pathological cases (buffer of one byte).  These should be added.

Comment: Toby, I truly appreciate your review.  I  strongly agree with `clearerr()` lack of comment is a short coming. `clearerr()` is warranted  yet subtle and deserves an explanation.  The last  _line_  lacking a `'\n'` is more forgiving to accept as a _line_ than to discard it as many text files lack a final `'\n'`. See also 7.21.2 2 `const` in parameters that are stable is perhaps a good idea or not in a function implementation (I'm on the fence here), but is clutter in a .h file declaration. Clean-up of `tmp.bin` is a good idea. Writing in binary mode was done for exactness in creating test cases.

Comment: I definitely *wasn't* suggesting a useless `const` in the header file - sorry if I gave that impression!  Definitely only in the definition and not in the header file's declaration.  I think I see your point about writing in binary mode - unfortunately, I don't think that using `tmpfile` will work if we need to do that, because we can't rewind and change the text/binary mode together.

Comment: `clearerr(stream);` rational:  When `readline_tostring()` returns  0 due to  _input error that just occurred_ or _line too long_, with embedded `clearerr(stream);`, calling `ferror()` absolutely distinguishes between those 2.  Without `clearerr(stream);`, calling `ferror()` is less certain since that may return true for a prior input error. Code could also examine `dest[0]`, yet that could be a read _null character_.  I suspected the line-too-long indication mechanism would the most troubling aspect of my code.  It would be more `fgets()`-like to not `clearerr(stream);`  Hmmmm.

Comment: BTW, I thought I had selected this answer to receive the bounty.  Yet somehow that failed and the answer was award the bounty by the community.