# Merging two files' lines of text for output

Tags: c, file, file-system

My program is supposed to merge two text files' lines together. For instance, if I have two files, `one.txt`:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

and `two.txt`:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

The output is:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m0 1 2 3 4
n o p q r s t u v w x y z5 6 7 8 9
```

However, I  feel as though some of the conditions are redundant. However, I'm not sure how I can better design this.

```
// Program to merge lines from two files and output results
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *inName1 = argv[1], *inName2 = argv[2];
    FILE *in1, *in2;
    int c, d;

    // Ensure correct usage
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./merge <file1> <file2>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input files and return if unable to open
    if ((in1 = fopen(inName1, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s.\n", inName1);
        return 2;
    }

    if ((in2 = fopen(inName2, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s.\n", inName2);
        return 3;
    }

    // Take care of output
    while ((c = getc(in1)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c != '\n')
            putc(c, stdout);        
        else
        {
            while ((d = getc(in2)) != EOF)
            {
                if (d != '\n')
                    putc(d, stdout);
                else
                {
                    putc('\n', stdout);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (d == EOF)
            {
                while (c != EOF)
                {
                    putc(c, stdout);
                    c = getc(in1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (c == EOF)
    {
        while ((d = getc(in2)) != EOF)
        {
            putc(d, stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(in1);
    fclose(in2);

    printf("\nProcess ended successfully.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So it's supposed to be exactly like `paste -d ''`?

Comment: Corner cases not specified: Consider `one.txt` and `two.ext` exist like above, but 1 of them lacks a final `'\n'`.  Should output contain a final `'\n'`?  (IMO, it should)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Some good things

This compiles cleanly with all my usual compiler warnings enabled - well done!

You've used `stderr` appropriately for the output (with the exception of the final message); that's good practice.

## Don't dereference `argv` before you've checked its bounds

This is wrong:

```
    char *inName1 = argv[1], *inName2 = argv[2];

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./merge <file1> <file2>\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

We can't read from `argv[1]` or `argv[2]` until *after* we know that `argc` is big enough:

```
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file1> <file2>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *inName1 = argv[1], *inName2 = argv[2];
```

I've enhanced your error message to use the actual name of the program, as passed in `argv[0]`.

## Report actual error type on failure

"Can't open " at least specifies which file couldn't be opened, but we can be more specific (file not found, permission denied, ...) using the `perror()` function:

```
    FILE *const in1 = fopen(inName1, "r");
    if (!in1) {
        perror(inName1);
        return 1;
    }
```

I also changed this to return `1` from any error - there isn't any great benefit in distinguishing the different causes in the error code.

## A slight tweak to the logic

The loops look mostly correct; there's a small duplication we can avoid here:

```
        while ((d = getc(in2)) != EOF)
        {
            if (d != '\n')
                putc(d, stdout);
            else
            {
                putc('\n', stdout);
                break;
            }
        }
```

We can bring the `putc()` outside the `if`-`else` like this:

```
        while ((d = getc(in2)) != EOF) {
            putc(d, stdout);
            if (d == '\n') {
                break;
            }
        }
```

## A redundant test

```
while ((c = getc(in1)) != EOF)
{
    /* ... */
}

/* c can only be EOF here */
if (c == EOF)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

## Consider some edge cases

You've taken good care to ensure that when one file ends, the rest of the other is output.  Have you thought about when to output a newline, if the ending file doesn't itself end with one.  It's not clear what you intend to happen in that case - comments should explain the desired output.

## Alternative logic

I prefer a less deeply nested set of loops, where the first loop is the "normal" case where we're reading from both files, and we leave that loop when *either* file is exhausted, and finish copying from the other:

```
int c, d;
// Take care of output
while ((c = getc(in1)) != EOF) {
    if (c != '\n') {
        putc(c, stdout);
        continue;
    }

    while ((d = getc(in2)) != EOF) {
        putc(d, stdout);
        if (d == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (d == EOF) {
        break;
    }
}

while ((c = getc(in1)) != EOF) {
    putc(c, stdout);
}
while ((d = getc(in2)) != EOF) {
    putc(d, stdout);
}
```

I've kept both `c` and `d` variables for this, although we only really need one for both files.

## Error checking of output

None of the above code ever checks the return value of `putc()`.  Filesystems do fill up, and users do disconnect streams and worse, so we really ought to ensure that the writes succeed.

## Error checking of input

We currently assume that `EOF` returned from `getc()` means that we've reached the end of the file.  However, it could mean that we have an error of reading, and we should distinguish those cases using `feof()` or `ferror()`.

## Final message

```
printf("\nProcess ended successfully.\n");
```

This isn't part of the output (and you don't want it to be passed along in a pipeline).  Send status messages to `stderr` - or better still, be silent whilst successful, like the standard utilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for  this! I, however, have some doubts. I haven't  learned much about error checking in I/O, so how would I go about checking the return value of `putc()` and `getc()`?  And why would using `perror()` make the program more specific? Does the fact that the `FILE *` points to `NULL` mean that the permission to access the file was denied?

Comment: Error checking - `if (putc(c, stdout) == EOF)` then something went wrong, and `c` was not written.  `perror()` uses the contents of `errno` (which is written by the failing function) to produce an error message (in the user's preferred language), such as "permission denied", or "file not found".  Read the man pages for all three of those functions, and you'll learn how to spot these details!

Comment: But wouldn't `(putc(c, stdout) == EOF) ` be redundant when the character I am scanning with `getc()` is always being evaluated agains `EOF`? I always end up outputting the character I read, don't I? And yes, I'll be reading the man pages for those! Thanks.

Comment: Read the man page for `putc()` again - it will return `c` when it succeeds, but *`EOF` when it fails* (and the reason will be noted in `errno`).

Comment: "we have an error of reading, and we should check that using errno."  --> `errno` is not specified to be set.  Use `feof()/ferror()` to distinguish end-of-file from   error.

Answer (score 3):

## Use functions to avoid repeating code

You have one big `main()` function that does everything. While this is a small program, it still is better to split off some logical pieces of code into their own functions. In this case, an operation that you repeat several times is copying one line of input from one input file to stdout. So write a function like this:

```
int copyline(FILE *in, FILE *out) {
     int c;

     // Copy all characters up to a '\n' or EOF
     while ((c = getc(in)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
         putc(c, out);
     }

     // This will return either '\n' or EOF
     return c;
}
```

Note how this function returns the last result from `getc()`.
In main, you can use it to simplify your code like this:

```
// Copy all lines from in1
while (copyline(in1, stdout) != EOF) {
    copyline(in2, stdout);
    putc('\n', stdout);
}

// Copy any remaining lines from in2
while (copyline(in2, stdout) != EOF) {
    putc('\n', stdout);
}
```

## Try to read whole lines instead of characters at a time

Now that you already have working code, you can think of optimizing it.
Your code reads and writes one character at a time. This might not be ideal.
Function calls like `getc()` and `putc()` are not free, and since they cannot be inlined, the compiler will have a hard time optimizing your loops.

If you can read and write whole lines at once, that would be better.
If you split of your line copying code into a function like `copyline()` above, then you only need to upgrade that function. One possibility is to use
the `fgets()` and `fputs()` functions that read and write whole lines at once.
Be aware though that `fgets()` can only read as many characters as the size of the buffer you supply (minus one), so you need to detect and handle longer lines somehow. Also, these functions assume you are working with C strings,
which use NUL bytes as terminators, and as such they will give you problems if
you want your program to be able to handle lines that contain NUL bytes.

Another option is to `fread()` the whole file into memory, or to use `mmap()` to map it into memory, and implement your own function to scan the memory for newline characters.

When optimizing code, make sure that you run benchmarks on the old and new implementations, never assume that a particular implementation is faster or slower than another one without having measured it.

## Close `stdout` and check for errors

You should call `fclose(stdout)` as well at the end, and check for errors. File output is buffered, and the `fclose()` call will ensure any buffers are flushed. Errors can definitely happen; for example, the user might have redirected stdout to a file, and the filesystem did not have enough space to hold the output.

If you silently ignore these errors, data corruption might happen more easily. For example, if you want to automate a process where two intermediate output files are generated, but you are only interested in the merged output, and will delete the temporary files afterwards, you might have a shell script that contains this line:

```
mergelines temp1.txt temp2.txt >result.txt && rm temp*.txt
```

By returning an error, you will have prevented the loss of the original files.
Note, [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/), the package that contains all the basic UNIX text processing utilities like `cat`, does exactly that.

## Try to make your program as generic as possible

Your program can merge the lines from two files, but what if someone wants to merge the lines from three files? This sounds like a very logical extension, and if you made your program a little bit more generic, you can easily handle an arbitrary number of input files. Just make an array of `FILE *` pointers, as big as `argc - 1`, and for each filename on the command line, open that file. Then copy lines from all open files, until all of them return `EOF`.

You might also want to allow specifying only one filename on the command line, or even none at all!

Comment: Er, your first `copyline()` copies more than just a line...  And the second may not be any faster than the first (that's the whole point of stdio - buffering to make char-by-char processing as fast as reading chunks at a time).  The other issue with that version is that it will treat any NUL character as line terminator (and drop the rest of the line).

Comment: Bug: `copyline(FILE *in, FILE *out)` only returns `EOF`.  Change to `while ((c = getc(in)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
           putc(c, out);
         }`

Comment: `if (line[len - 1] == '\n')` is UB when `line[0] == '\0'`.

Comment: `copyline()` (via `fgets()`) would make more sense to loop if the `line[]` was full and no `'\n'` found - yet I now see the "You will need to detect and handle the case of longer lines".  Better to comment such code  limitations in the code.

Comment: Very good "In main, you can use it to simplify your code like this:" code idea.

Comment: Thanks @chux, I fixed `copyline()` per your suggestion and added some more comments. Note that `line[len -1]` is never UB here because `len` is never 0, because `fgets()` never returns an empty line.

Comment: @TobySpeight: char-by-char processing is slow even if it is buffered for two reasons: even a buffered `getc()` is not free, and you are doing some processing for every character. Now you will say: "but don't `fgets()` and `strlen()` do such per-character processing behind the scenes themselves?" That might be true, but most C libraries will have very well optimized implementations for these commonly used functions. You are very right about the NUL characters.

Comment: @G.Sliepen "because fgets() never returns an empty line." is not  so empty  concerning null character input.  If user input is _null character_, _line feed_, then `line[]` will get written with the 2 characters: _null character_, _line feed_, and an appended _null character_.  A lead _null character_ is not as uncommon as one may think.  Recall that `fgets()` stops reading when it encounters a `'\n'`.  If it reads `'\0'`, it saves that null character and continues like any other non-`'\n'`.  Since `strlen(line)` then returns 0, `line[len - 1]` is UB.

Comment: @chux: ah, I seem to have missed that possibility, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @G.Sliepen `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';` is a  one-line alternative to lop off the potential `'\n'` without UB.   `fgets()` and _null character_ input is problematic though. My sample [alternative](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179201/fgets-alternative)

Comment: On the last point, is it actually necessary to handle more than two files?  We *could* make the code more generic as you suggest; the alternative viewpoint says that we keep the code simple (and - importantly - more easily tested) by allowing one of the files to be the standard input stream, and then we can pipeline processes to merge as many files as we wish.  (Note: I'm not claiming that your advice is at all unsound, just that there are different philosophies on this, and it's not clear that either one is indisputably better).

Comment: Char-by-char processing *might* be as fast as line-by-line - my point was that we need measurements to be sure.

Comment: @TobySpeight: keeping things simple is good, I agree, but in this case consider that other text processing tools, like `cat`, also allow an arbitrary number of arguments, and it will be surprising if your tool does not. Also, while you could pipeline processes together, how easy is it? Consider having a directory with an arbitrary number of text files, would you rather just write `mergelines *` or write some complicated shell script that either uses recursion or temporary files to work around the two argument limitation?

Comment: Yep, that's a good argument for the generality (I'm also fond of the "zero, one, many" rule, which suggests the same thing).