# A function to scan user input as string

Tags: c, strings, functional-programming, dynamic-programming

I know that multiple functions are already available. However, I thought of writing my own because I wanted to learn the logic (and also because I thought there wasn't enough confusion :P). Please review the function I wrote and suggest me efficient changes.

Without further ado, here I go:

```
scan(string,size)
char** string;
size_t size;
{
    string[0]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char keystroke=' ';
    while((keystroke=getc(stdin))!='\n') {
        string[0][size++]=keystroke;
        string[0]=(char*)realloc(string[0],size+1);
    }
    string[0][size]='\0';
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is horrible:

- You don't check for end-of-file, which will lead to endless loops
- You don't check for failure of `malloc` or `realloc`
- You call `realloc` way too often, which makes the code slow for large lines of input
- You cast the result of `malloc`
- You use the outdated style of function definition from the 1980s
- The variable `string` is not a string but points to an array of pointers to strings, which is confusing
- The `#include` for `size_t` is missing
- Using `[0]` instead of `*` is extremely confusing
- There is no need to initialize `keystroke` to a space character
- The parameter `size` is useless since the only possible value that makes sense for it is 0
- The return type of the function is implicitly `int`, which is obsolete
- The returned value is of type `size_t`, which doesn't fit into an `int` and additionally differs in signedness

Comment: Firstly, why would I check for EOF?? That being said, size_t defaults to unsigned long int in my system, (It seems, there was an error copying the code which I will fix immediately; thanks for pointing that out). Oh, yeah, and also I will add malloc and realloc failures (wonder how I forgot that??). Thanks :)

Comment: Anyways, I edited the function to incorporate your suggestions 2,4,6,7,12.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 "why would I check for EOF?" --> to know when `stdin` has no more data to provide.

Comment: Well, that work is accomplished by '\n', isn't it? I mean, have I got the concept wrong?? Like, for e.g., I type in `3 4 t 5 6` and press enter, the array shows the required characters. Whatever the size of the input, it works. Do try it and tell me. :)

Comment: Here's the link --> https://github.com/kesarling/SL-V/blob/master/assignment2/main.c

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 what if the input ends before you can read a '\n'?

Comment: The input is being given by stdin, i.e. the terminal. \n denotes the end of the input; that's what.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31, When `stdin` is _closed_, `getc(stdin)` returns `EOF` - that is the true end of input.  Your code, instead of stopping, goes into an infinite loop.  `'\n'` is only the end of a _line_.

Comment: Oh!! you mean to say like, if someone uses freopen to point stdin to a file? Well, umm..in that case, my code will wait

Comment: But, in any other case, won't EOF be returned after user presses enter? In that case, it will have already broken the loop

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 It does not wait, it loops, consuming memory until an allocation failed and then UB of attempting to de-reference a `NULL`.  Loop should quit on either `'\n'` and `NULL`.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Because you have not tested it in enough different cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103846/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-d4rk4ng31).

Answer (score 2):

Code does not handle end-of-file or rare input error well as there is no attempt to detect `EOF`.

Perhaps something like

```
// char keystroke=' ';
int keystroke=' ';
while((keystroke=getc(stdin))!='\n' && keystroke!= EOF) {
    string[0][size++]=keystroke;
    string[0]=(char*)realloc(string[0],size+1);
}
if (keystroke == EOF && size == 0) {
   free(string[0]);
   string[0] = NULL;
   return -1;  // Maybe use (size_t)-1 to indicate EOF.
}
```

Fuller [example code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/179201/29485)

Comment: any particular reason to use `int keystroke` over `char keystroke` ?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 `int getc(stdin)` returns type `int` and typically 257 different values.  To save in `char` loses information.  Using `char`, cannot distinguish `EOF` from a valid character.