# fgets without the line return

Tags: c

What do you think of the following function to offer an alternative to fgets, looking for insights about portability, safety, readability and performance:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int sc_gets(char *buf, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    char c;

    if (__glibc_unlikely(n <= 0))
        return -1;

    while (--n && (c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n')
        buf[count++] = c;
    buf[count] = '\0';

    return (count != 0 || errno != EAGAIN) ? count : -1;
}

#define BUFF_SIZE 10

int main (void) {
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE];

    sc_gets(buff, sizeof(buff)); // how to use
    printf ("%s\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

*NB: I have already read [fgets() alternative](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179201/fgets-alternative) which was interesting but my code is different.*

---

Second version thanks to the comments and vnp's insight:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

long sc_gets(char *buf, long n)
{
    long count = 0;
    char c;

    while (--n && (c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        buf[count++] = c;
    }
    buf[count] = '\0';

    return (count != 0 || errno != EAGAIN) ? count : -1;
}

#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

int main (void) {
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    sc_gets(buff, sizeof(buff));
    printf ("%s\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use implementation specific API `__glibc_unlikely()` it is probably best to wrap them in a macro to provide alternatives for implementations that don't have them.

Comment: I already checked about them, there is no need to replace them as "the platforms that don't support them just define them to expand to empty strings. " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-their-ben

Comment: I think you misunderstand that. This is systems that know about `likely`/`unlikely` but don't implement it will expand to white space. Implementations that don't understand it don't automatically do something special to support it. I could be wrong (does the language standard say something special)?

Comment: It looks good to me, but @MartinYork is right, portability is not guaranteed, I ran it in a Windows environment both with gcc version 9.2.0 (tdm64-1) POSIX adapted version, and with MSVC and the compilation fails for both with `undefined reference to __glibc_unlikely'` and `unresolved external symbol __glibc_unlikely` respectively.

Comment: The unlikely is likely (pun intended) a premature optimization. `fgetc` will do locking io and kill performance. POSIX and Windows both have unlocked stdio, but they do it differently. `int` as the size type matches `fgets`, but I'd still have gone foe `size_t`

Comment: Is there an error too: doesn't eat `\n` if the line has n-1 characters?

Comment: @Antti love the pun! How comes pthread has such optimizations if it is not portable?

Comment: long is not size_t. long on wibdows has exact same representation as int.

Comment: Excellent point, forgot about this. What would you suggest then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The function does not handle end-of-file correctly. `stdin` is just a stream, and could be closed like any other stream. For example, type `Ctrl-D`. Or

  ```
    echo -n a | ./a.out
    a????????
  ```

  Keep in mind that reading beyond end-of-file doesn't set `errno`.
- There is no reason to special-case `count == 0`.

  An IO error doesn't break the loop. If it happened, all the subsequent invocations of `fgets` would return `EOF`, and upon the loop termination the `count` will be `n`.
- Pass the buffer size as `size_t`. This is what `sizeof` yields, and the buffers could be large enough for their size to overflow an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight, please have a look at version 2 :)